# how to set up cache in a winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, caching

I couldn't find decent examples of how to accomplish simple caching in winforms c#
this is what i've come up with but I get exceptions.

// this line already gets an exception
   ICacheManager productsCache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager("MyCacheManager");

the exception is:
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0,

the app.config which I think I am unable to config properly is:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="cachingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="MyCacheManager">
        <cacheManagers>
            <add name="MyCacheManager" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60" maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="1000"
                numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="10" backingStoreName="NullBackingStore" />
        </cacheManagers>
        <backingStores>
            <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                name="NullBackingStore" />
        </backingStores>
    </cachingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

I used the entlib config to create the app.config
I keep getting exceptions. is there an example I can use? (something more up-to-date than examples from 2007)

10x for your time

Answer (score 0):

The Caching assembly depends on Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common. Your project needs to reference the Common assembly as well as Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.  Also, make sure the versions in your bin folder match the version specified in your configuration file.  If the config is generated using a version of the configuration tool that uses a different copy of the assemblies, it can create a version mismatch.

Can also check out the post below for some other ideas:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2007/04/19/avoiding-configuration-pitfalls-with-incompatible-copies-of-enterprise-library.aspx

Comment: both are referenced. is there anything more I can do?

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Comment: Actually the config file does not address the common.dll what so ever and the other file which is caching.dll is mentioned correctly in the config file. so I still haven't figured out why I can't load the assembly